# Como faço para colocar um campo de senha em um MessageBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Como inserir um campo que eu possa colocar uma senha em um `MessageBox`.

Eu poderia chamar um *form*, mas queria algo mais simples e rápido, gostaria que quando eu clicasse em um botão ele fornecesse um campo para colocar uma senha que será definida mais a frente, essa senha irá liberar a função do botão.

Comment: sei que não é um MessageBox, porém existe o InputBox, que é uma mensagem onde o usuário pode entrar com alguma informação, como no seu caso é uma senha, não seria legal deixar ela visível, então encontrei [esse link](http://www.vbforfree.com/set-inputboxes-input-to-be-password-characters/) (código em VB.NET) que define uma máscara na entrada do usuário, caso você tenha interesse!

Comment: Obrigado Mateus.
E gostaria de saber o que nao ficou claro na pergunto, pq assim eu possa esclarecer.

Comment: @FelipeWalleg tem uma pessoal meio maluco aqui. Pior que foi votado depois de ter uma resposta aceita. O que eu te aconselho é tentar escrever de forma mais organizada, separar mais em parágrafos sempre que possível, pensasse antes de escrever, não colocar como se tivesse falando. Isso ajuda o pessoal perceber clareza. Aproveita e não coloque saudações nem antes nem depois. Pense nisto como uma pergunta de uma prova. Já viu pergunta dar bom dia ou dizer obrigado? Aqui é um site de perguntas e resposta e não um fórum.

Comment: Entendi, bigown

Comment: A Função `InputBox()` não da suporte para esconder os caracteres, mas é uma `MessageBox` com uma caixinha de texto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é possível, o `MessageBox` foi criado para emitir alertas e não para entrada de dados.

Você terá que criar um [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) e usar um [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) nele. Poderá usar [`PasswordChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_PasswordChar) para esconder os dados digitados.

Se quiser simular o comportamento chamado *modal* do `MessageBox` é possível usar o [`ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog) no formulário normal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, eu gostaria de evitar esse método mas pelo visto não terá escapatória, rsrs
Obrigado mais uma vez!